# Multi-Threaded NLP with Spacy pipe

Tags: python, multithreading, nlp, pipeline, spacy

I'm trying to apply Spacy NLP (Natural Language Processing) pipline to a big text file like Wikipedia Dump. Here is my code based on Spacy's [documentation](https://spacy.io/docs) example:

```
from spacy.en import English

input = open("big_file.txt")
big_text= input.read()
input.close()

nlp= English()    

out = nlp.pipe([unicode(big_text, errors='ignore')], n_threads=-1)
doc = out.next()
```

Spacy applies all nlp operations like POS tagging, Lemmatizing and etc all at once. It is like a pipeline for NLP that takes care of everything you need in one step. Applying pipe method tho is supposed to make the process a lot faster by multithreading the expensive parts of the pipeline. But I don't see big improvement in speed and my CPU usage is around 25% (only one of 4 cores working). I also tried to read the file in multiple chuncks and increase the batch of input texts:

```
out = nlp.pipe([part1, part2, ..., part4], n_threads=-1)
```

but still the same performance. Is there anyway to speed up the process? I suspect that OpenMP feature should be enabled compiling Spacy to utilize multi-threading feature. But there is no instructions on how to do it on Windows.

Comment: What does `n_threads` do? Is there a reason you've set it to less than 0?

Comment: it sets the number of Threads to be used. I guess -1 means it will be automatically specified and does not enforce a specific number to it

Comment: Have you tried setting a positive number to it?

Comment: Yes I did but no luck

Comment: @AkshatMahajan `-1` means to use all the available CPUs.

Comment: I've found a way to do this with current spacy and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60170624/4494

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured what the problem was. OpenMP is the package used in implementing multithreading for spacy pipe() method. This option is disabled for MSVC compiler by default. After I compiled the source code with openmp support it works great. I also made a [pull request](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/pull/329) to enable this on the next releases. So for releases after 0.100.7 (which is the latest version) multithreading with pipe() should work on Windows with no issue.

Comment: Hi SJ, 

Any idea how do you get the sentences out of pipe. I have a huge doc like you. A text string. I do nlp.pipe(txt). 

Now I was hoping I can simply use .sents on this but it doesn't work. 

How do you extract nlp pieces from pipe generator

Comment: The syntax has changed in new version of Spacy. You first load a language model and then apply nlp to a text. "The pipeline used by the default models consists of a tagger, a parser and an entity recognizer. Each pipeline component returns the processed Doc, which is then passed on to the next component." https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines